# Pulling another bit of data from delimited string for query results

Tags: t-sql

I use the code below to extract a piece of data that is so many along in the delimited string after a certain character or number appears, I wish to pull another piece of data to appear before each of these values being pulled. 
I do not fully understand how the code works, although I do understand elements of it. I just wish to repeat the process of pulling and integrate it into the query results.

```
USE RUG_Data 

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#splitoutdata','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #SPLITOUTDATA;
CREATE TABLE #SPLITOUTDATA (
    INDEX1 INT,
    ROWNUM INT,
    BITOFDATA VARCHAR(max));


IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Split_XML', N'TF') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION dbo.Split_XML
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split_XML
    (
     @Parameter VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@Delimiter VARCHAR(1)
    )
RETURNS @Result TABLE
    (
     ItemNumber INT
    ,ItemValue VARCHAR(MAX)
    )
AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @XML XML ;
        SET @Parameter = ( SELECT   @Parameter
                         FOR XML PATH('')
                         ) ;
        SELECT  @XML = '<r>' + REPLACE(@Parameter, @Delimiter, '</r><r>') + '</r>' ;

        INSERT  INTO @Result
                (
                 ItemNumber
                ,ItemValue
                )
                SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL) ) AS ItemNumber
                ,       Item.value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS ItemValue
                FROM    @XML.nodes('//r') R ( Item ) ;
        RETURN ;
    END ;
GO


;WITH
REFORMATTEDDATA AS
(
SELECT  
    row_number()over(order by (select null)) as INDEX1,

    REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(DATA AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10),'')AS RAWCLOB2
FROM
    RUG_CLOB
WHERE
    CAST(DATA AS VARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE 'ZHV|FS0000%%%|D0003001%'
)



INSERT INTO #SPLITOUTDATA 
SELECT 
      INDEX1, 
      ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY INDEX1 ORDER BY split.ItemNumber) AS ROWNUM,
      split.ItemValue AS BITOFDATA 
 FROM REFORMATTEDDATA
 CROSS APPLY dbo.Split_XML(reformatteddata.RAWCLOB2,'|') SPLIT


CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX idx1 ON #SPLITOUTDATA (INDEX1,ROWNUM)


SELECT

    [Date], [MPAN],
    [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],
    [20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31],[32],[33],[34],[35],[36],[37],[38],[39],[40],[41],[42],[43],[44],[45],[46],[47],[48],[49],[50] 

FROM
( 
    SELECT 
    INDEX1, 
    (SELECT BITOFDATA FROM #SPLITOUTDATA so2 WHERE so2.INDEX1 = so1.INDEX1 and so2.ROWNUM = 8) AS [Date] ,
    (SELECT BITOFDATA FROM #SPLITOUTDATA so2 WHERE so2.INDEX1 = so1.INDEX1 and so2.ROWNUM = 14) AS [MPAN] ,

    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY INDEX1 ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS ROWNUM, 




    (SELECT BITOFDATA FROM #SPLITOUTDATA so4 WHERE so4.INDEX1 = so1.INDEX1 AND so4.ROWNUM = so1.ROWNUM +3) AS BITOFDATA 
    FROM #SPLITOUTDATA so1 
    WHERE BITOFDATA = '012' 


        --  AND 
        --(SELECT BITOFDATA FROM #SPLITOUTDATA so5 WHERE so5.DC_INDEX_FK = so1.DC_INDEX_FK AND so5.ROWNUM = 10) NOT IN ('TR01')
    ) p 
    PIVOT 
        (MAX (BITOFDATA) 
    FOR ROWNUM IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31],[32],[33],[34],[35],[36],[37],[38],[39],[40],[41],[42],[43],[44],[45],[46],[47],[48],[49],[50]) 
) AS PVT



IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#splitoutdata','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #SPLITOUTDATA;
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Split_XML', N'TF') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION dbo.Split_XML
```

At the moment my query results show as –

```
[Date], [MPAN],
[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],
[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31],[32],[33],[34],[35],[36],[37],[38],[39],[40],[41],[42],[43],[44],[45],[46],[47],[48],[49],[50]
```

I wish to have

```
[Date], [MPAN],
[E/A],[1], [E/A], [2], [E/A], [3], [E/A], [4], [E/A], [5], [E/A], [6], [E/A], [7], [E/A], [8], [E/A], [9], [E/A], [10], [E/A], [11], [E/A], [12], [E/A], [13], [E/A], [14], [E/A], [15], [E/A], [16], [E/A], [17], [E/A], [18], [E/A], [19], [E/A],[20], [E/A], [21], [E/A], [22], [E/A], [23], [E/A], [24], [E/A], [25], [E/A], [26], [E/A], [27], [E/A],[28], [E/A], [29], [E/A], [30], [E/A], [31], [E/A], [32], [E/A], [33], [E/A], [34], [E/A],[35], [E/A],[36], [E/A], [37], [E/A], [38], [E/A], [39], [E/A], [40], [E/A], [41], [E/A], [42], [E/A], [43], [E/A], [44], [E/A], [45], [E/A], [46], [E/A], [47], [E/A], [48], [E/A],[49], [E/A], [50]
```

The E/A value is also within the delimited string and features one piece before the value I am pulling every time so I assume in some way I will use this bit of code to pull it:

```
(SELECT BITOFDATA FROM #SPLITOUTDATA so4 WHERE so4.INDEX1 = so1.INDEX1 AND so4.ROWNUM = so1.ROWNUM +2) AS BITOFDATA 
FROM #SPLITOUTDATA so1 
WHERE BITOFDATA = '012'
```

I just can’t get it to work for some reason as I’m fairly new at this but I assume it’s fairly simple.

Sorry if I haven't explained it very well.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without sample data, but you should be able to PIVOT a second time on the results of your PIVOT to get the results you're after

Comment: ZHV|FS0000392|D0003001|C|SSIL|X|FSEX|20120821104133||||TR01|
007|2300000000000|
008|E451234|
009|20120831120000|S|
010|02|AE|
011|20120831|
012|01|A|7.0|||||
012|02|A|7.0|||||
012|03|A|7.0|||||
012|04|A|7.0|||||
012|05|A|7.0|||||
012|06|A|7.0|||||
012|07|A|7.0|||||
012|08|A|7.0|||||
012|09|A|7.0|||||
012|10|A|7.0|||||
012|11|A|7.0|||||
012|12|A|7.0|||||
012|13|A|7.0|||||
012|14|A|7.0|||||
012|15|A|7.0|||||
012|16|A|7.0|||||
012|17|A|7.0|||||
012|18|A|7.0|||||
012|19|A|7.0|||||
012|20|A|7.0|||||
012|21|A|7.0|||||
012|22|A|7.0|||||
012|23|A|7.0|||||